# How to modify the array structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to development and have started working with arrays and objects. I want to modify the below structure.

```js
[{
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-16",
  "details": [{
    "type": "algo",
    "count": 1
  }, {
    "type": "Code",
    "count": 35
  }]
}, {
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-08",
  "details": [{
    "type": "algo",
    "count": 2
  }, {
    "type": "Code",
    "count": 70
  }]
}]
```

This is the final structure that I want:

```js
[{
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-16",
  "type": "algo",
  "count": 1
}, {
  "build": "Build 1",
  "date": "2019-08-16",
  "type": "code",
  "count": 35
}, {
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-08",
  "type": "algo",
  "count": 2
}, {
  "build": "Build 2",
  "date": "2019-08-08",
  "type": "code",
  "count": 70
}]
```

Is there any way to do this in Javascript or jQuery? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Just FYI, the data structure you have is an array of objects. It has nothing to do with JSON, so I edited that out of your question

Answer (score 5):

You could take (upcoming) [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the details and a [rest in object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring).

Then map both objects.

```js
var data = [{ build: "Build 1", date: "2019-08-16", details: [{ type: "algo", count: 1 }, { type: "Code", count: 35 }] }, { build: "Build 2", date: "2019-08-08", details: [{ type: "algo", count: 2 }, { type: "Code", count: 70 }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(({ details, ...o }) => details.map(p => ({ ...o, ...p })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1 for being quicker than me, and giving a more elegant implementation :) It's worth noting that `flatMap()` is unsupported in IE and Edge, though

Answer (score 0):

Approach without `flatMap`

```
// data is your JSON

return [].concat(...data.map(({details, ...object}) => details.map(detail => 
  ({
      ...detail,
      ...object
  }))
))
```

Comment: Your avoidance of `flatMap()`, presumably in an attempt to make this work cross-browser, is made redundant by your use of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility), as that won't work in IE or Edge in this scenario, either.

Comment: Agree, but spread operators are more supported than `flatMap`. Used to caniuse.com for this statistics

Comment: `spread operators are more supported than flatMap` That's true, but in this case neither will work in any version of IE, and as you're using the spread within an object, it won't work in Edge.